# Should i choose ogre 3d or unity 3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ogre

I'm new to game development.i'm good at c++,c,python so programming is not my problem. but i'm confused between ogre 3d and unity 3d (free version).i know that both are different ogre is something like API and unity is game engine. but i'm really confused which to use for my project. i've 1 month for the project and i need to develop a game with good graphics in small time. can anyone direct me to a right path.? can anyone give me pros and cons of unity and ogre..?.

in short, which one is better for game development..?..ogre or unity (free version)..?

Comment: Sounds like it's impossible to answer, given just that you're write a game. A checkers game? A first person shooter?  Minesweeper meets tower defence? :-) The question is for you to answer, because you know your game concept and requirements.  That being said, Ogre seems pretty awesome to me, and so does Unity3d. Unity3d doesn't seem to be just an engine at all, it also has tools.

Comment: Consider posting a more detailed question to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Warren P: I'd like to see minesweeper meets tower defense.

Answer (score 5):

"Better" is a relative term, because each has pros and cons. Ogre has the advantage that it's more flexible and more low-level so if you are intending to become a game programmer (it sounds like this is a programming assignment) then you are going to learn more useful stuff from it. However Unity is MUCH simpler to use and thus you'll get more done in the month.